# Powershell script failing from teamcity, running fine upon manual run

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a powershell script which creates a new login in a database.
The script runs fine when I run from powershell ISE or console but it fails when I run it from Teamcity or use teamcity command manually.

```
C:\windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -File C:\DB_Deploy\DB_Deploy.ps1 && exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The error I get is

> Validation Error: Error while checking backup file

The .bak backup file is at a shared remote location.

I suppose the problem, while running from teamcity, is in opening the backup file.

The same runner config works for other powershell scripts, the ones not involving opening of any file on remote location.

Comment: Does the user that your CI serer is running under have enough privileges to access the backup file? Did you run this under the CI server's user from your machine as a test?

Comment: Yes. With the same user i am running manually and its working.

Comment: The CI user has administrator rights, supposedly the highest role.

Comment: If you're running TeamCity agent as a service, try [starting it manually](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-ManualStart). 
Also, it would be helpfull if you showed the "DB_Deploy.ps1" script that is failing, or at least the lines that you suspect are causing trouble.